# Data being overwritten in this one specific scenario

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to JS and HTML and there are many things I'm trying to understand so if anyone can help and explain it'd be great.

Here's my snippet.

```
<script>
$(".radio-inline").click(function(){
 $("#team").click(function(){
    create_Countdown(data[2].year, data[2].month, data[2].day, data[2].Hours, data[2].ampm, data[2].minute, data[2].second); 
   });
});
</script>
```

For some reason whenever I call the create_Countdown() function within the jquery functions it is generated on an all blank page. I am assume that all the other code is being deleted for some reason. The weird thing is that if I call the function without call the jquery function it prints where I want it to.

Can anyone help?

For those asking to see the code for create_Countdown() here it is

```
function create_Countdown(yearx, monthx, dayx, hourx, ampmx, minutex, secondx){ //Code to create a new countdown with the parameters
    new Countdown({year  : yearx, 
    month : monthx, 
    day   : dayx, 
    hour  : hourx,
    ampm  : ampmx,
    minute  : minutex, 
    second  : secondx});
```

}

I tried to put a return before new to see if there would be a difference and nope.

Comment: Great, so where is the code for `create_Countdown`? (Also, I'm going to take a wild guess here that you're using `document.write` and that will be the cause of your issue ;) )

Comment: Try to explain your code in human language to yourself and you would figure out what the problem is. (tips: two click events one binds inside another and there are missing brackets in it). Spend some time to learn JavaScript before learning jQuery, believe me it will pay off later.

Comment: For those asking for the code to create_Countdown here it is

Comment: Ok, what does your Countdown class look like? Creating a jsfiddle might help.

Comment: @aj_r I'm using his countdown.js gieson.com/Library/projects/utilities/countdown

Comment: I see what you mean. I've created a JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/gnhtb1cp/1/) and I'm getting the same problem. My guess is it's an issue with Countdown. I'll see if I can find a way to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by looking at their "Advanced Options" example. Basically, you need to specify a target where the Countdown will be created (otherwise it seems to use `document.write` or something that messes up your html).

First you need this somewhere in your html:

```
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Then, in your javascript:

```
function create_Countdown(yearx, monthx, dayx, hourx, ampmx, minutex, secondx) {
    new Countdown({
        year   : yearx, 
        month  : monthx, 
        day    : dayx, 
        hour   : hourx,
        ampm   : ampmx,
        minute : minutex, 
        second : secondx,
        target : "countdown" // A reference to an html DIV id
    });
}
```

This tells Countdown to create itself inside of an existing HTML element instead of its default behavior.

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/gnhtb1cp/5/

Comment: Dude you are unbelievable. Thank you so much, this thing has been driving me crazy for the past two days.

Comment: I'm new to SOF, how do I help you build reputation?

Comment: Mainly by answering people's questions. http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Answer (score 1):

why are there click handlers nested inside of each other?

```
$(".radio-inline").click(function(){
   // when I click .radio-inline
   // then attach click handler to #team element
   $("#team").click(function(){
      //then when I click #team , after I have click radio-inline
      //then create count_countdown
        create_Countdown(data[2].year, data[2].month, data[2].day, data[2].Hours, data[2].ampm, data[2].minute, data[2].second); 
   });
});
```

Comment: I'm still tinkering with html to learn all the syntax and how to access each class and id. I thought I had to access each area one by one (c++ coder for 3 years). I removed the radio-inline click function, but the issue persists.